# Java sort List <SqlRow> by date as String

Tags: java, string, list, sorting, date

I have a list from the Type  and I would like to sort this list by an element of date. I googled and I saw some solutions with comparable, but is there a possibility to do this without implementing the interface in my class?
My list looks like as in the following:
list[{id=33, text=test1, date=06.02.15}, {id=81, text=test2, date=10.01.15}]
Now I would like to compare both elements and would like to order them descending by date. But date is also in String.
Do you have any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In the title you're speaking of a list of SqlRows. I guess they come from a database, then why don't you sort them directly in your query?

Comment: You could use Collections.sort() method. It accepts a list of un-comparable items and a Comparator<Type> object. You have just to implements Comparator without implementing Comparable interface

Comment: @StephaneM You are right, they are coming from a database. The problem is that the date is also in the db as stored as varchar2. I tried it to implement it as date, but I get too many errors and trouble. So that it make more sense to work with varchar2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if date is stored in varchar2 than firstly Convert them to an actual Date object,

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd h:m");
System.out.println(sdf.parse(dateFromDataBase));
```

and then do the comparing on date Objects

```
if(date1.compareTo(date2)>0){
// Do whatever you want to do 
}
```

Now coming to the sorting of `List<SqlRow>`

you can use `comparator Interface` as mentioned by **@Srinivasu Talluri**
but if you are not interested in using these interfaces which literally make you life easy than you can use either [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) or [Insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) and compare on the basis of `dates` as mentioned above

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(Type, new Comparator<Type>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Type o1, Type o2) {
          SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd h:m");
          Date d1 = sdf.parse(o1.date);
          Date d2 = sdf.parse(o2.date);
          return d1.compareTo(d2);
      }
  });
```

Comment: @NeerajJain that's not `Comparable` but `Comparator`.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the type is here? My list looks like this: List<SqlRow> rows = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql).findList();

Comment: @user3725212 then use `Collections.sort(rows, new Comparator<SqlRow>() { ... });`. I don't think it's a good idea to work with `List<SqlRow>` to begin with but probably that's how the app you're working with is designed.

Comment: His dates are stored into varchar2 so you comparator will fail

Comment: One quick answer i can give is insted of storing the data in varchar2, date into long {java.util.Date.getTime()}

Comment: If I am using another type as varchar 2, my delete, update and create updates with ebean will fail in Java. The easiest and more robust way is to work with varchar2. But then I have the problem that the generated lists from the database are not sorted in the right way, because the date is stored as String. So either I change the whole database and make more changes in the Java code or I find a way to sort the list in the right way. The 2. solution will be better, because I dont need to change many things in the app.